# Android - How to navigate by Route Legs?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-navigation, google-directory-api

I'm building an app which will show route to the user to specific destination.
I get the route from Google direction web service.

But I don't understand how should I know in which leg the user is now?
Or, which legs have already been passed?

Comment: Google doucumentaiom tellling what leg fields contain https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Legs

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but how can i know in what step i'm now based on the curent location?

Answer (score 0):

The way to find out the leg in which user is currently positioned is to find the values in the steps[] array, if those steps match with another steps[] array in one of the leg than that particular leg is the one in which the user is currently located.

Code logic would have some conditional if else statement where a check would be made to figure out the steps in one of the leg fetched from the API and the steps user currently is.

Hope that Helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the situation. The route is parsed from json response from Google directions to custom class. I need to figure out which step the user is in now based on his LatLang location.